# IIS 7 - CodeIgniter Application name error 404 if not in correct case

Tags: codeigniter, iis, url-rewriting

I host my CodeIgniter website under IIS 7 with application name NewApp. So the URL can be reach on URL "my-domain.com/NewApp". The landing page can be access through "my-domain.com/newapp" link. But when I tried to access the other page like "my-domain.com/NewApp/Module" using "my-domain.com/newapp/Module" URL format, it gave me 404 error.

I have tried to un-tick the "ignore case" under "URL Rewrite" section but it makes "my-domain.com/newapp/Module" accessible and "my-domain.com/NewApp/Module" error 404.

Here is the setting that I applied on the IIS "URL Rewrite" section
[image]

**Update Aug 12, 2015**

1. The working application name is depend on what URL that we accessed after IIS Application Pool recycle period. So if I access "newapp" after the recycle period, we cannot access "NewApp". The same behaviour also applied when I access "NewApp" at the first time.
2. I found out that if I call codeigniter function $this->uri->uri_string() on "newapp" (assume I run "NewApp" after recycle period) the string that returned by the function is "NewApp/Controller/Function". And if I call the same function on "NewApp" it will returned "Controller/Function"

The temporary solution is to modify the router core class to make the function return the same output string.

Is there anyone know what to do in IIS so I don't use this temporary solution?

Comment: Hi @Narf, i know i'm new here. But may i know why you edit my question and said the question/tag is not relevant? Because without put the word that you said is irrelevant the audience will think this is the regular website that host under IIS. I have tried to host an ASP.Net website and ASP.Net MVC website and all of them are fine. Only the website that I made using the word that you removed that have the problem

Comment: And you had to put my nickname in the question itself now? I removed the references to CodeIgniter because your question is quite obviously not related to it - everything that you're describing is about URL rewriting and that happens at the IIS level, not in CodeIgniter. Just because you're using CI for the underlying application, that doesn't mean it's relevant.

Comment: Hi @Narf, the problem is I don't know on which part that of the technology that cause this problem. I just listed the technology that i use to build the website. It would be better if you contribute on how to answer/solve the question and know the meaning of the question before you edit someone post. It's not polite for me if you directly edit someone post without knowing their purpose

Comment: I don't know IIS, but I know CodeIgniter enough to know that it is not the source of your problem and by removing references to it, I'm narrowing down the question for you - I *am* contributing that way. If you don't appreciate that, then fine, you can just rollback my edit, but don't involve me in this flame war.